# C Why function pointer as parameter instead of just a function?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have been reading about having functions with functions as parameters, and particulary in C, they use function pointers. Let's suppose I want to implement the newton raphson method (in a simple way) for computing zeros in non linear equations.

```
double derivative(double f(double), double x)
{
    double h = 1e-9;
    return (f(x + h) - f(x)) / h;
}

double newton_raphson(double f(double), double x0, double tol)
{
    double xk, diff;

    do
    {
        xk = x0 - f(x0) / derivative(f, x0);
        diff = fabs(xk - x0);
        x0 = xk;
    } while (diff >= tol);
    return xk;
}
```

So, to compute an approximation for derivative I need a function that returns a double and takes a double as an argument. Same for computing a root of the function, given the other parameters. My question is, why is this different from declaring function parameters as function pointers? For instance declaring the input parameter f as a function pointer instead of just a function...

Comment: what is function? from assembly point of view for example?

Comment: Have you tried your version? Does it compile?

Comment: The parameter `f` is a function pointer...

Comment: @dandan78: [It compiles](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'',source:'double+derivative(double+f(double),+double+x)%0A%7B%0A++++double+h+%3D+1e-9%3B%0A++++return+(f(x+%2B+h)+-+f(x))+/+h%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

Comment: Not immediately relevant but your solution is not particularly numerically stable: your derivative function will be rather unpredictable. NR may well overshoot the root or oscillate around it. If that does happen then you can always fail over to a bisection search or even brent.

Comment: Yeah, it was just a quick example, I know it is not stable for some functions that vary quicker than the h defined...

Comment: @Bathsheba: I'd be more concerned with the fact that the derivative is apparently calculated numerically from the function itself.

Comment: @EOF that's what I mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter `f` is a pointer-to-function in both `derivative` and `newton_raphson`.

```
double derivative(double f(double), double x) { ... }
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
double derivative(double (*f)(double), double x) { ... }
```

Only, the former looks nicer - usually when you can omit parentheses, you should probably do so. After all both of them are equivalent to

```
double ((((derivative)))(double (((*(f))))(double ((trouble))), double ((x)))) { ... }
```

That I hope will only ever be used in IOCCC.

---

However, if you're declaring, defining a variable (not a function parameter), you need to use

```
double (*f)(double);
```

as

```
double f(double);
```

is just a function declaration.

---

*6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)* of C11 draft n1570 says:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning
>   type
>   ’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘pointer to
>   function returning
>   type
>   ’’, as in 6.3.2.1.

And
*6.9.1 Function definitions* further says that

> [...]  the  type  of  each  parameter  is  adjusted  as described in 6.7.6.3 for a parameter type list; the resulting type shall be a complete object
>   type.

additionally it has the following example:

> **EXAMPLE 2**
>
> To  pass one function to another, one might say
>
> ```
> int f(void);
> /* ... */
> g(f);
> ```
>
> Then the definition of `g` might read
>
> ```
> void g(int (*funcp)(void))
> {
>       /* ... *
>       (*funcp)(); /* or funcp(); ... */
> }
> ```
>
> **or, equivalently,**
>
> ```
> void g(int func(void))
> {
>       /* ... */
>       func(); /* or (*func)(); ... */
> }
> ```

Comment: So it does not matter if i define it as double derivative (double (*f)(double)...

Comment: Yes, in C arguments that are arrays rewrite to object pointers, argument that are functions rewrite to function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Like normal data pointers, a function pointer can be passed as an argument and can also be returned from a function. A function’s name holds the address of function.

> My question is, why is this different from declaring function parameters as function pointers? For instance declaring the input parameter f as a function pointer instead of just a function...

The answer is that both forms will be treated as same by compiler.
But for readibility of your code, go with the kind of declaration that your example code has, i.e.,

```
double derivative(double f(double), double x) { ... }
```

Even in C, the function definitions given below will be interpreted as same-

```
void foo(int a[]) // or int a[10]
{
     ...
}

void foo(int *a)
{
     ...
}
```