# Function as parameter to function

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters, function-pointers

I just noticed that this compiles without any errors or warnings using `-pedantic -Wall` with both `gcc` and `clang`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 0;

void func(int f(const char *)) {
    f("func()!");
}

int main(void) {
    func(puts);
}
```

It appears that the parameter `f` is treated like  pointer to function `int (*)(const char *)` in this case.

But this a behavior that I have never seen or heard anything about. Is this legal C code? And if so then what happens when you have a function as a parameter to a function?

Comment: Function pointers are valid parameters, you can pass for example different callback functions with them. The function which receives them, then can call that function, no problem there.

Comment: In this case the type of the parameter is is written as a "function" and not as a "pointer to a function" in which case it would have been declared `int (*f)(const char *)` instead.

Comment: This is syntactic sugar and is allowed to make declarations easier to read. See the first comment to the accepted answer of the duplicate question.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Obviously not a dup. The questions are not the same, the answers are not the same. A comment happens to explain the problem, but that doesn't make it a dup.

Comment: It was already answered here: [How do you pass a function as a parameter in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c)

Comment: @dogusyuksel, where? I can not see any reference to what OP is asking in the duplicate

Comment: This one seems a better duplicated: [C Why function pointer as parameter instead of just a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36578503/1606345)

Comment: @unwind OP is asking how is this syntax permitted by the standard not how to pass a function. You closed it incorrectly.

Comment: @KeineLust That is the correct duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is allowed by the standard. From C99 standard chapter 6.9.1 (took from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> EXAMPLE 2 To pass one function to another, one might say
>
> ```
> int f(void);
> /*...*/
> g(f);
> ```
>
> Then the definition of g might read
>
> ```
> void g(int (*funcp)(void))
> {
>     /*...*/
>     (*funcp)(); /* or funcp(); ... */
> }
> ```
>
> or, equivalently,
>
> ```
> void g(int func(void))
> {
>      /*...*/
>      func(); /* or (*func)(); ... */
> }
> ```